# How to divide 1 column with other and then use the same formula and apply it to other columns in R

Tags: r, csv, division

I am Very new to this page and also in R
I have one csv file
that file contain
6 column

**name | expression | mean_of_control | mean_of_test1  | mean_of_test2 | mean_of_test3**

I want to divide
mean_of_control/mean_of_test1 and save it as new column saying FC_test1
similarly
mean_of_control/mean_of_test2 and save it as new column saying FC_test2
mean_of_control/mean_of_test3 and save it as new column saying FC_test3
this FC_test1 FC_test2 FC_test3 should be in one csv file
how can I write code for this?
I don't want to use same formula three times.
I just want code that I can use this formula and apply for all the column.

Comment: your question is blurry...try to edit it so it is clearer and be more specific.

Comment: (Yes, it's obvious you are "new", but you don't need to remain unaware of the local rules and conventions. This is not a chat room.) Suggest you spend time studying and then implementing an appropriate response to [mcve]. Also suggest you learn to add periods at the ends of sentences and apply appropriate capitalization to improve readability. Not my downvote but I do understand it.

Answer (score 1):

We create a vector of column names for `mean_of_test` ('nm1') and the new columns ('nm2') (so that not to repeat the whole strings again), then use `Map` to divide the 'mean_of_control' by the subset of columns based on 'nm1' to create the new columns by assigning (`<-`)

```
nm1 <- paste0("mean_of_test", 1:3)
nm2 <- paste0("FC_test", 1:3)
df1[nm2] <- Map(`/`, list(df1$mean_of_control), df1[nm1])
```

---

Or using `vectorized` methods, we can just replicate the 'mean_of_control' to make the lengths same and then divide from the 'mean_of_test' columns

```
df1[nm2] <- df1[nm1]/df1$mean_of_control[col(df1[nm1])]
```